# Integrating kendoui with relational activerecord in PHP

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, pdo, kendo-ui

I am working on [kendoui](http://kendoui.com) and Yii to integrate them to work together seamlessly.

The main problem I am facing is that kendoui official samples are using PDO in their PHP wrappers.

But Yii mainly uses DAO or ActiveRrcord or Relational ActiveRecord.

And Yii recommends Relational Active Record. The same choice is given by my developers team.

So any idea on how to migrate kendoui samples to Relational Active Record (in data manipulation).

At least if I find a way to migrate one simple sample I will make it to all other samples. I googled a lot with no hope.

Comment: have you seen this? https://github.com/paulovin/yii-kendoui

Comment: yes for sure. But he doesn't implement yii models or activerecord. The only thing he's doing is statically send data to grid as json array.